# How to determine if an Azure StorageV2 (Data Lake Storage with Hierarchical namespace) BlobItem is a Virtual Directory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have the following code:

```
var client = new BlobServiceClient("connection string");
var container = client.GetBlobContainerClient("my-container");
await foreach(var item in container.GetBlobsAsync()) {
   // do something about the item if it is a file
}
```

I found that there is no way to determine if the item is a virtual directory or a file.  I had also tried `client.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync`, the folder still shows up as a BlobItem not a Prefix.  What am I missing here?

** Edit for clarification.
I am using Azure Storage Account blob containers.  There are past similar posts and the answers suggested that directory is not supported in ABS.  But Azure moves at a pretty fast pace.  Please see that attached screenshot.  They sure looks like directories to me.

** Edit for further clarification.
It seems that there are two "Kinds" of storage account.  In the Storage accounts UI, they are indicated as either "Storage" or "StorageV2". StorageV2 has Hierarchical namespace = enabled under "Data Lake Storage" properties.  I will updated the title accordingly.

[image]

Comment: there are no virtual directories in ABS. GetBlobsAsync is going to return you each individual blob item inside that container.

Comment: Pretty certain that Directories are being returned by GetBlobsAsync.  My problem is that there is no distinction between Directory and File.  They are all BlobItems.

Comment: They are all certainly blob items, that is the thing, there is no 'directory' in ABS.  in Azure data lake storage Gen2 there is directory based organization, not in Azure Blob storage.

Comment: @RushuiGuan Please show us your **actual** output from `container.GetBlobsAsync` - such as a screenshot of your debugegr's Watch/Locals window.

Comment: @RushuiGuan - I just tested with your code to list blobs in a container that has virtual folders. The code did not return virtual folders. All blobs were returned. You should use [`BlobContainerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsbyhierarchy?view=azure-dotnet) if you want virtual folders to be listed.

Comment: To work with ADLS Gen 2 accounts, please use `Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake` Nuget package instead of `Azure.Storage.Blobs`.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri.  If you enter your previous comment as an answer, I would mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADLS GEN 2 accounts (V2 Storage accounts with hierarchical namespace enabled) are built on top of blob storage. What that means is that some of the features available in blob storage are available for ADLS GEN2 accounts as well.

For most parts, you can use [`Azure.Storage.Blobs`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs) SDK for managing the data in your ADLS GEN2 accounts.

However there are some additional features which are only available in ADLS GEN2 accounts (e.g. first class support for folder hierarchy, POSIX support etc.). In order to take advantage of these additional features and manage them, you would want to use [`Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake) SDK instead of `Azure.Storage.Blobs`.